# App update issue on google play market

Tags: android

We have updated our app to new version 2.1.31.But it is showing 2.1.28 on website of google play and 2.1.31 on google play mobile app.Please help here.
Also many users find new version of our app in app description but no update button is shown,only open and uninstall is there.

Please note that we have rolled out an app with 100%.

Thanks

Comment: how long since you updated? It can take like 24 hours to do a full rollout

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: @TimCastelijns Updated 1 week ago